# Focus a p:inputText after actionListener

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a actionListener in ManagedBean that make some process and i need focus a specific inputText after this proccess is finished. So i have this commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-play" value="Continuar" id="commandButtonContinuar"
                            actionListener="#{arMB.salveAndContinue}"
                            update=":formManterAr:dialogManterAr"
                            oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) {varDialogManterAr.show();}" />
```

And i need to focus this inputText bellow, after commandButton is complete.

```
<h:outputText value="Nome Destinatário: *" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{arMB.bean.nomeDestinatario}" required="true"
                    widgetVar="varDestinatario" id="destinatario"
                        requiredMessage="O nome é obrigatório" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the oncomplete function to call the method focus of your input text so

```
oncomplete="focusChange()"

<script type="text/javascript">
        function focusChange(){
            $('varDestinatario').focus();
        }
</script>
```

You can also check the [focus](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/focus.jsf) component the prime faces

Comment: I already tried it, but didn't work. I tried in this way: oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) {varDialogManterAr.show(); $('#varDestinatario').focus();}"

Comment: And the component "p:focus" i have no ideia how to use to focus a specific component in form

Comment: You can check running the script $('#varDestinatario').focus() on the chrome console and check if there is an error, here is a blog entry about the prime faces focus http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/focus-management-with-primefaces/

Comment: any erros are show in console and component p:focus don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-play" value="Continuar" id="commandButtonContinuar"
                        actionListener="#{arMB.salveAndContinue}"
                        update=":formManterAr:dialogManterAr"
                        oncomplete="focusfn()" />

 function setFocus() {
      document.getElementById('formId:destinatario').focus();   
 }
```